# "CacheProfile" in MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, outputcache

I am beginner in MVC and I have a project to transform from MVC2 to the latest version of MVC. 
I read read some books on MVC 4, so I started to understand the main mechanisms.

However, when transforming my MVC 2 solution, I have a problem with an attribute: `OutputCache`.

By eg. I have multiple Actions like this (the attributes may vary):

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ProductImage")]
public ActionResult GetImage(Guid elementId, int imgtype)
```

in the Web.Config i have in the "caching>outputCacheSettings>outputCacheProfiles>":

```
<add name="ProductImage" duration="5" varyByParam="elementId,imgtype" />
```

and obtaining the following exception in output:

> OutputCacheAttribute for child actions only supports Duration,
>   VaryByCustom, and VaryByParam values. Please do not set CacheProfile,
>   Location, NoStore, SqlDependency, VaryByContentEncoding, or
>   VaryByHeader values for child actions.

As I understood, the problem appears only with the child actions.

- Is there another way to have a cache profile in the latest MVC?
- Is there a way to identify if the action is a child one in order to modify just that action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved installing [MvcDonutCaching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDonutCaching/) nuget and replacing `[OutputCache` with `[DonutOutputCache`...

See [more](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) about.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution that works and I would recommend

Answer (score 0):

Please read the answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410431/outputcache-attribute-on-clientside-with-partial-pages), I believe it answers your question pretty well.

Comment: The solution there didn't work for me and also has some other devs advising against it.