# outputCacheProfiles with Redis cache

Tags: azure, caching, redis, outputcache, output-caching

I have an MVC web project and I am trying to setup OutputCache for some of the pages using redis cache running locally, eventually to be hosted in azure.

I have decorated my **ActionResult** with

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "cacheprofile1")]
```

and have the following in my web.config under system.web / caching

```
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="cacheprofile1" duration="1800" varyByParam="none"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
```

My Cache provider is set accordingly

```
     <outputCache defaultProvider="localRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <add name="localRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" host="127.0.0.1" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
```

No entries are being made into my cache. If I change my ActionResult decoration to

```
[OutputCache(Duration=1800)]
```

it works, but I'd rather not have to set this manually against each method.

Any ideas on why the cache profile is being ignored and how to resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set outputCache settings inside <system.web></system.web>?

Comment: outputCache is being set within caching under <system.web> so
<system.web>
<caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <add name="localRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" host="127.0.0.1" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
      <outputCacheSettings>
         <outputCacheProfiles>
         </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829479/